# appending to file with bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

using:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please, enter name"
read NAME
echo "$NAME," >> MyFile$(date +%m%d%Y)
echo "done"
```

it will append the `NAME` to the file without issue, however, I want it to append the existing line in the file rather than starting a new line with each append

For example:

```
bob,sarah,jane,
```

instead of what I have currently happeneing which is:

```
bob,
sarah,
jane,
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo -n ....`.  It usually allows to output string **without** end of line mark.

```
echo -n "$NAME," >> MyFile$(date +%m%d%Y)
```

Comment: While `echo` usually works, it's not very portable. Different versions of `echo` use different means for suppressing the newline. A more portable solution is to use `printf`, e.g., `printf "%s" "$NAME," >> Myfile$(date +%m%d%Y)`.

Comment: @Augamire: If this is what you wanted, then your question wasn't very clear.  Do you realize that this solution will permanently maintain your file in a state of not ending with a newline?  That might cause programs not to handle it correctly.

Comment: @G-Man I apologize if my question is unclear. I am very new to bash. Does the next echo statement not create the ending with a newline? What would your recommendation be for a solution to the challenge I face, if not the -n option?

Comment: What "next echo statement"?  The `echo "done"`?  That goes to the script's standard output (stdout); I presume that that is the terminal, or at least something other than YourFile.  The question suggests (to me) that you were looking for something like `sed -i "\$s/\$/$NAME,/" "MyFile$(date +%m%d%Y)"`.

Comment: @G-Man I think I see what you are getting at. In this case, I am actually appending to an existing netgroup config where I do not want to end with a newline, as the line will be appended to frequently & a new line will, as I underdstand it, actually break the environment without other changes also being executed.

Comment: Well, in that case, Andrzej's answer is exactly what you want.  But I don't see any hint of what you just said in the question.  Also, having the last line end with a newline will "actually break the environment"?  That would be unusual.

Comment: @G-Man I didn't add any of it in the original question as I did not see the relevance at the time, however, you have opened my eyes to the narrow sightedness of that thought process. Thank you so much for the info - I really learned a lot from the discourse. I agree it is unusual to break the environment in this way.

Comment: @garyjohn than you for the comment. I was able to incorporate this into other parts of my scripts.